# CSS margin-top is not getting applied on all printed pages with HTML table

Tags: html, css, printing

I'm trying to print multi page invoice using `table` in `HTML`. However the `margin-top` of `body` is not getting applied in all pages. The top of first page is having margin as expected. But the second page starts at bleeding top edge without margin.

Here are the screen shots:

**First Page:**

[image]

**Second Page:**

[image]

I tried adding margin inside `@page` as show below but doesn't work.

```css
@page {
    size: A4;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
```

Here is the code:

```html
<html>

<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        @media print {
            #section-to-print {
                position: absolute;
                left: 0;
                top: 0;
            }

            body {
                font-family: Calibri, monospace;
                font-size: 0.8rem;
                margin: 1rem;
                border: 1px solid;
            }

            body ol {
                list-style: none;
                padding-left: 0;
                margin: 0.5rem 0;
            }

            table {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                border-collapse: collapse;
                page-break-inside: auto;
            }

            td section div {
                page-break-inside: avoid;
            }

            thead {
                display: table-header-group;
            }

            tfoot {
                display: table-footer-group;
            }

            header {
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: column;
                font-weight: normal;
            }

            #brand {
                border-bottom: 1px solid;
                padding: 0.25rem 0.5rem;
                text-transform: uppercase;
                font-weight: bold;
            }

            #invoicedetails {
                display: grid;
                grid: "shop customer invoice";
                grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
                padding: 0 0.5rem;
                border-bottom: 1px solid;
            }

            #shop {
                text-align: left;
            }

            #customer {
                border: 1px solid;
                border-top: 0;
                border-bottom: 0;
                padding-left: 0.5rem;
                text-align: center;
            }

            #invoice {
                text-align: right;
            }

            table tbody td {
                height: 100%;
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: column;
                justify-content: space-between;
            }

            main {
                display: block;
                height: 100%;
            }

            #invoiceitems {
                display: block;
                height: 100%;
                text-transform: uppercase;
            }

            #itemscontent {
                height: 100%;
                display: grid;
                grid: "sno isbnno title price quantity amount";
                /*Below line is added as inline style in A4 invoice component*/
                /*grid-template-rows: repeat(2, minmax(1rem, max-content)) auto repeat(2, minmax(1rem, max-content));*/
                /*grid-template-columns: minmax(min-content, max-content) minmax(min-content, auto) max-content max-content max-content max-content max-content max-content;*/
                grid-auto-rows: minmax(1rem, max-content);
                grid-column-gap: 1px;
                align-items: center;
            }

            #itemscontent>div {
                display: flex;
                align-items: center;
                border: 1px solid;
                height: 100%;
                border-top: 0;
                border-right: 0;
                padding: 0 0.25rem;
            }

            .border-left-0 {
                border-left: 0 !important;
            }

            .span-4 {
                grid-column-start: span 4;
            }

            .flex-end {
                justify-content: flex-end;
            }

            footer {
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: column;
            }

            #itemsfooter {
                display: flex;
                justify-content: space-between;
                align-items: center;
                text-transform: uppercase;
                border-top: 1px solid;
            }

            #itemsfooter>div {
                align-self: stretch;
                display: flex;
                align-items: center;
                padding: 0 0.5rem;
            }

            #amountinwords {
                flex: 75%;
            }

            #totalamount {
                flex: 25%;
                text-align: right;
                border-left: 1px solid black;
            }

            #totalamount ol {
                width: 100%;
            }

            #totalamount ol li:last-child {
                font-size: x-large;
            }

            #invoiceinformation {
                display: flex;
                justify-content: end;
                padding: 0 0.5rem;
                border-top: 1px solid;
                border-bottom: 1px solid;
            }

            #signature {
                padding-left: 0.5rem;
            }

            #message {
                display: flex;
                justify-content: space-between;
                align-items: center;
                padding: 0 0.5rem;
            }
        }
    </style>
    <style type="text/css">
        @media print {
            @page {
                size: A4;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body onload="window.print();"><!--!-->
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <header>
                        <section id="brand">COMPANY LOGO</section><!--!-->
                        <section id="invoicedetails">
                            <section id="shop">
                                <ol>
                                    <li>From</li><!--!-->
                                    <li><b>COMPANY NAME</b></li><!--!-->
                                </ol>
                            </section><!--!-->
                            <section id="customer">
                                <ol>
                                    <li>To</li><!--!-->
                                    <li><b>CUSTOMER NAME </b></li><!--!-->
                                </ol>
                            </section><!--!-->
                            <section id="invoice">
                                <ol><!--!-->
                                    <li>Invoice Details</li>
                                    <li> Invoice No: <b>9/2023-24</b></li><!--!-->
                                    <li>Invoice Date: <b>10 Oct 2023</b></li><!--!-->
                                    <li>Payment Mode: <b>Cash</b></li><!--!-->
                                    <li>Payment Status: Paid</li>
                                </ol>
                            </section>
                        </section>
                    </header>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead><!--!-->
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <main>
                        <section id="invoiceitems">
                            <section id="itemscontent"
                                style="grid-template-rows: repeat(2, minmax(1rem, max-content)) auto repeat(3, minmax(1rem, max-content)); grid-template-columns: minmax(min-content, max-content) minmax(min-content, max-content) minmax(min-content, auto) max-content max-content max-content">
                                <!--!-->
                                <div class="border-left-0 border-top-0">S.No</div>
                                <!--!-->
                                <div class="border-top-0">ISBN No</div>
                                <!--!-->
                                <div class="border-top-0">Title</div>
                                <!--!-->
                                <div class="border-top-0">Price</div>
                                <!--!-->
                                <div class="border-top-0">Quantity</div>
                                <!--!-->
                                <div class="border-top-0">Amount</div>
                                <div class="border-left-0">1</div><!--!-->
                                <div>123-456-789-0</div><!--!-->
                                <div>அக்கா</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="flex-end">1</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="border-left-0">1</div><!--!-->
                                <div>123-456-789-0</div><!--!-->
                                <div>அக்கா</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="flex-end">1</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="border-left-0">1</div><!--!-->
                                <div>123-456-789-0</div><!--!-->
                                <div>அக்கா</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="flex-end">1</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="border-left-0">1</div><!--!-->
                                <div>123-456-789-0</div><!--!-->
                                <div>அக்கா</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="flex-end">1</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="border-left-0">1</div><!--!-->
                                <div>123-456-789-0</div><!--!-->
                                <div>அக்கா</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="flex-end">1</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="border-left-0">1</div><!--!-->
                                <div>123-456-789-0</div><!--!-->
                                <div>அக்கா</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="flex-end">1</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="border-left-0">1</div><!--!-->
                                <div>123-456-789-0</div><!--!-->
                                <div>அக்கா</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="flex-end">1</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="border-left-0">1</div><!--!-->
                                <div>123-456-789-0</div><!--!-->
                                <div>அக்கா</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="flex-end">1</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="border-left-0">1</div><!--!-->
                                <div>123-456-789-0</div><!--!-->
                                <div>அக்கா</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="flex-end">1</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="border-left-0">1</div><!--!-->
                                <div>123-456-789-0</div><!--!-->
                                <div>அக்கா</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="flex-end">1</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="border-left-0">1</div><!--!-->
                                <div>123-456-789-0</div><!--!-->
                                <div>அக்கா</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="flex-end">1</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="border-left-0">1</div><!--!-->
                                <div>123-456-789-0</div><!--!-->
                                <div>அக்கா</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="flex-end">1</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="border-left-0">1</div><!--!-->
                                <div>123-456-789-0</div><!--!-->
                                <div>அக்கா</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="flex-end">1</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="border-left-0">1</div><!--!-->
                                <div>123-456-789-0</div><!--!-->
                                <div>அக்கா</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="flex-end">1</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="border-left-0">1</div><!--!-->
                                <div>123-456-789-0</div><!--!-->
                                <div>அக்கா</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="flex-end">1</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="border-left-0">1</div><!--!-->
                                <div>123-456-789-0</div><!--!-->
                                <div>அக்கா</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="flex-end">1</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="border-left-0">1</div><!--!-->
                                <div>123-456-789-0</div><!--!-->
                                <div>அக்கா</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="flex-end">1</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="border-left-0">1</div><!--!-->
                                <div>123-456-789-0</div><!--!-->
                                <div>அக்கா</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="flex-end">1</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="border-left-0">1</div><!--!-->
                                <div>123-456-789-0</div><!--!-->
                                <div>அக்கா</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="flex-end">1</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="border-left-0">1</div><!--!-->
                                <div>123-456-789-0</div><!--!-->
                                <div>அக்கா</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="flex-end">1</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="border-left-0">1</div><!--!-->
                                <div>123-456-789-0</div><!--!-->
                                <div>அக்கா</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="flex-end">1</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="border-left-0">1</div><!--!-->
                                <div>123-456-789-0</div><!--!-->
                                <div>அக்கா</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="flex-end">1</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="border-left-0">1</div><!--!-->
                                <div>123-456-789-0</div><!--!-->
                                <div>அக்கா</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="flex-end">1</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="border-left-0">1</div><!--!-->
                                <div>123-456-789-0</div><!--!-->
                                <div>அக்கா</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="flex-end">1</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="border-left-0">1</div><!--!-->
                                <div>123-456-789-0</div><!--!-->
                                <div>அக்கா</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="flex-end">1</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="border-left-0">1</div><!--!-->
                                <div>123-456-789-0</div><!--!-->
                                <div>அக்கா</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="flex-end">1</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="border-left-0">1</div><!--!-->
                                <div>123-456-789-0</div><!--!-->
                                <div>அக்கா</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="flex-end">1</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="border-left-0">1</div><!--!-->
                                <div>123-456-789-0</div><!--!-->
                                <div>அக்கா</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="flex-end">1</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="border-left-0"></div>
                                <div></div>
                                <div></div>
                                <div></div>
                                <div></div>
                                <div></div>

                                <!--!-->
                                <div class="border-left-0 flex-end span-4">Sub Total</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">1</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div>
                                <div class="border-left-0 flex-end span-4">Discount </div><!--!-->
                                <div></div>
                                <div class="flex-end">-₹30.00</div><!--!-->
                                <div class="border-left-0 flex-end span-4">Postage &amp; Packing Fee</div>
                                <div></div>
                                <div class="flex-end">₹50.00</div>
                            </section>
                        </section>
                    </main><!--!-->
                    <footer>
                        <section id="itemsfooter">
                            <div id="amountinwords">
                                <ol>
                                    <li><small>Total Amount in Words (INR)</small></li><!--!-->
                                    <li><b>one hundred and twenty ONLY</b></li>
                                </ol>
                            </div><!--!-->
                            <div id="totalamount">
                                <ol><!--!-->
                                    <li><small>Total Amount</small></li>
                                    <li><b>₹120.00</b></li>
                                </ol>
                            </div>
                        </section><!--!-->
                        <section id="invoiceinformation">
                            <div id="signature"><text>for COMPANY NAME<!--!--><br><br><br>Authorized
                                    Signatory</text></div>
                        </section><!--!-->
                        <!--!-->
                        <section id="message">
                            <div><small>THANK YOU FOR FOR THE BUSINESS</small></div>
                            <div><small>THIS IS A COMPUTER GENERATED INVOICE</small></div>
                        </section>
                    </footer>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Note: Due to restriction in question body character limit, I have removed few `<div>` in my code sample. In case if multiple page is not appearing then please copy paste below code inside body enough 30 times to get second page.

```html
                                    <div class="border-left-0">1</div><!--!-->
                                    <div>123-456-789-0</div><!--!-->
                                    <div>அக்கா</div><!--!-->
                                    <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div><!--!-->
                                    <div class="flex-end">1</div><!--!-->
                                    <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div><!--!-->
```

Please assist me on what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I have no solution for it, but I recommend you to break pages before every table, so the table will start at the top of the page.

```
<table class="table" >
```

in css:

```
@media print {
  .table{
    page-break-before: always;
  }
}
```

Comment: The page will always have only one table.